# Прокачка алгоритмов

Tags: алгоритм

Маленькая предыстория.
Я студент(3 курс), на днях ходил в большую контору, учавствовал в тесте(Набор стажеров). Те, кто прошел тест, пошли на интервью. Я не прошел. Задачи в тесте были типа чисто алгоритмическите(вида сделайте что-то не превышая сложность алгоритма равную Х и не превышвая столько то памяти). Всю свою учебу программирую, не 24/7 но достаточно качественно(В реальной задаче я думаю смог бы разобраться).В моих задачах почти не встречалось алгоритмических задач. 
 С чего начать прокачивать алгоритмическую основу?
Если быть более точным, то какие книги можете посоветовать ну или вообще любые советы есть, то будет лучше.

Answer (score 13):

Книги:

- Кормен "Алгоритмы. Построение и анализ"
- Седжвик "Алгоритмы на Java"
- Кнут "Искусство программирования"

На coursera.org Седжвик ведет курс :

- [Algorithms, Part I](https://www.coursera.org/course/algs4partI)
- [Algorithms, Part II](https://www.coursera.org/course/algs4partII)

И конечно же не пренебрегайте упражнениями.

Comment: за книжки спасибо:)

так же есть курсы на эту (и другие)  темы от CS клуба

http://www.lektorium.tv/university/?id=2677

Comment: Кормен наше все =). Однако без практики далеко не уйдешь, и самый лучший способ научиться разбираться в алгоритмах - нарешивать задачи. Благо есть где:
acm.timus.ru  
acm.mipt.ru  
acm.sgu.ru  
uva.onlinejudge.org  
spoj.pl
codeforces.ru  
topcoder.com/tc
и другие.

Answer (score 1):

[Построение и анализ вычислительных алгоритмов  А. Ахо, Дж. Ульман, Дж. Хопкрофт](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=316916)